# Grid Computing and Logged out

Tags: grid-computing

Does grid computing continue when the user is not logged in - for instance, on an educational system, where students must log in, when the log out, does the cpu continue the cloud computing? Or in another instance, if I use my home computer for something like superdonate.com, does the processor still go if I log out?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client and how it is set up. But I think most clients continue to work when you log off.

 The whole purpose is to use the computer when it is idle after all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic. Technically, if you have delegation of credential, yes. In Globus you delegate authentication credential to a third part, and it will continue acting on your behalf even if you "log out".